# how can I use node modules within frida scripts?

Tags: node.js, frida

I'm trying to use some node modules in Frida, I'm using the latest version of Frida.
The module I'm trying to use is 'fs'.I'm using, of course, frida-compile to compile the code into a runnable code with frida.
When I run the following code, I get the error: No such file or directory.

```
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
var addr = JSON.parse(readFileSync("addresses.json"));
console.log(addr);
```

I simplified the code, frida does not support the node environment so I can't use require.
I already used frida-fs and got the same error.
the file exists in the current directory, I tried using both relative and absolute path but I still get the same result.

Comment: I already mentioned that I'm using frida-compile, and the error I'm getting is with the compiled script.

Answer (score -1):

```bash
$ npm i frida-compile demangler-js -g
```

add to your script

```js
const demangle = require('demangler-js').demangle;
...
Module.enumerateExportsSync('library.so')
  .filter(x => x.name.startsWith('_Z'))
  .forEach(x => {
    Interceptor.attach(x.address, {
      onEnter: function (args) {
        console.log('[-] ' + demangle(x.name));
      }
    });
  });
```

compile

```bash
$ frida-compile script.js -o out.js
```

run

```bash
$ frida -Uf com.app -l out.js
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `ReferenceError: 'require' is not defined at <anonymous> (module_test.js:1)`

Comment: You did not run frida-compile or you ran frida with script.js instead of out.js

Comment: I copied exactly your posted commands, I only changed the app name. Tested on a jailbroken iOS and rooted Android device using Frida 16.0.11 on PC and phone side. Node.js: v18.13.0.